# Build workflow to build an eclipse rcp application by feature builds

Tags: hudson, eclipse-rcp, maven-3, tycho

I'm searching for an build workflow to build an eclipse rcp application by **feature builds** with maven 3 with tycho and hudson.

My Example:

**3 Features**

- Feature A
- Feature B
- Feature C

**2 Products**

- Product 1 - Based on features A and B
- Product 2 - Based on features B and C

For every feature and product exists one Hudson job. My requested workflow is that

1. every feature will be builded and deployed and then
2. every product will be created on the base of the deployed features.

Is there any *best practive* workflow for that (with an tutorial in the best case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this to work by using the same local Maven repositories in all jobs. When you call e.g. the feature A build with `mvn clean install`, the build result will be visible to all Tycho build that run on the same local repository.

Note that you should probably put a Hudson lock on the shared local Maven repository, because Maven and Tycho don't access that repository in a multi process safe way.